# I18n localization/Merging not working in Angular 10 after upgrading from Angular 7

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular10, xliff

Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 12.14.1
OS: win32 x64

```
    \\Angular: 10.1.6
    \\... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    \\... language-service, localize, platform-browser
    \\... platform-browser-dynamic, router
    \\Ivy Workspace: Yes

    Package Version
    @angular-devkit/architect 0.13.10
    @angular-devkit/build-angular 0.1001.7
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer 0.13.10
    \\@angular-devkit/build-webpack 0.1001.7
    @angular-devkit/core 10.2.0
    @angular-devkit/schematics 10.2.0
    @angular/animations 10.2.1
    \\@angular/cdk 10.2.6
    @angular/cli 10.2.0
    @angular/http 7.2.16
    @angular/material 7.3.7
    \\@ngtools/webpack 10.2.0
    @schematics/angular 10.2.0
    @schematics/update 0.1002.0
    \\rxjs 6.6.3
    typescript 4.0.5
```

---

Above mentioned is my configuration for Angular 10.

We have recently upgraded from Angular 7 to Angular 10.
Our project supports 4 different locales and we were handling localization through below commands.

---

```
"extract-i18n": "ng xi18n \\projectName --i18n-format \\xlf --output-path assets/locale --i18n-locale && ng run \\projectName:xliffmerge"**
```

---

This was working fine in Angular 7. But now it has stopped working for us and gives error as

---

```
ERROR: language "C:\Users \\centraluser\source\repos\FinxFrontend2\node_modules@ngx-i18nsupport\ngx- 
    i18nsupport \\xliffmerge \\xliffmerge" is not valid ERROR: language 
    "C:\Users \\centraluser\source\repos\FinxFrontend2\node_modules@ngx-i18nsupport\ngx- 
    i18nsupport \\xliffmerge\xliffmerge" is not valid ERROR: i18nFile \\messages.xlf is not readable
```

---

Is there any other way to extract and merge already created \xlf files?

Comment: On executing below command

---- ng xi18n angular --format=xlf --output-path assets/locale && ng run angular:xliffmerge

it gives below error ----

An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for builder @ngx-i18nsupport/tooling:xliffmerge
See "C:\Users\CENTRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-r6zg82\angular-errors.log" for further details.

if something comes up your mind??

Comment: it seems like xliffmerge doesn't work in angular 10 anymore. I have generated the message.xlf file but now I need to merge it with other already generated localized files(es, fr, de) etc.

Is there some other tool or command which I can use for the same??

Answer (score 0):

Check this tool https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular9-app-with-xlf-files

I have the same problem as you when updating to Angular 11, it seems that the xliffmerge tool is no longer supported and there are no updates in the Github repository. Babel's translation program merges the xlf files that you enter, establishing the primary language you can translate in as many languages ​​as you need and the string extraction is always performed on the primary language.